# two array one in price and productname and the second is username, quantity, productname how to group this two array in one by username using pure js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here's my arrays:

```
let prices = [
    {
        product: "p1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        product: "p2",
        price: 120.2,
    },
    {
        product: "p3",
        price: 120,
    },
    {
        product: "p4",
        price: 125,
    },
]

let orders = [
    {
        user: "user1",
        product: "p1",
        quantity: 2,
    },
    {
        user: "user1",
        product: "p1",
        quantity: 4,
    },
    {
        user: "user4",
        product: "p3",
        quantity: 5,
    },
    {
        user: "user4",
        product: "p4",
        quantity: 10,
    },
    {
        user: "user3",
        product: "p2",
        quantity: 10,
    },
    {
        user: "user4",
        product: "p1",
        quantity: 10,
    },
    {
        user: "user1",
        product: "p2",
        quantity: 10,
    },
    {
        user: "user3",
        product: "p2",
        quantity: 20,
    }
]
```

How can I group it by user so that I would get the result of:

```
result = [
    {
        user: "user1",
        product: [
            {
                productName: "p1",
                quantity: 6,
                itemPrice: 100,
                totalPrice: 600
            }
        ],
        total: 600
    },
    {
        user: "user4",
        product: [
            {
                productName: "p3",
                quantity: 5,
                itemprice: 120,
                totalPrice: 600
            },
            {
                productName: 'p4',
                quantity: 10,
                itemprice: 125,
                totalPrice: 1250
            }
        ],
        total: 1850
    }
]
```

Comment: See `.reduce` functionality https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 1):

You could find the group of customer first and then find the item and create the product of price and quantity.

For easier access of prices, you could use an object `pricesByProduct`.

```js
const
    prices = [{ product: "p1", price: 100 }, { product: "p2", price: 120.2 }, { product: "p3", price: 120 }, { product: "p4", price: 125 }],
    orders = [{ user: "user1", product: "p1", quantity: 2 }, { user: "user1", product: "p1", quantity: 4 }, { user: "user4", product: "p3", quantity: 5 }, { user: "user4", product: "p4", quantity: 10 }, { user: "user3", product: "p2", quantity: 10 }, { user: "user4", product: "p1", quantity: 10 }, { user: "user1", product: "p2", quantity: 10 }, { user: "user3", product: "p2", quantity: 20 }],
    pricesByProduct = Object.fromEntries(prices.map(({ product, price }) => [product, price])),
    result = orders.reduce((r, { user, product: productName, quantity }) => {
        let customer = r.find(q => q.user === user);
        if (!customer) r.push(customer = { user, product: [], total: 0 });

        let item = customer.product.find(q => q.productName === productName);
        if (!item) customer.product.push(item = { productName, quantity: 0, itemPrice: pricesByProduct[productName], totalPrice: 0 });

        let orderPrice = item.itemPrice * quantity;
        item.quantity += quantity;
        item.totalPrice += orderPrice;
        customer.total += orderPrice;

        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```